# C# Get MAC address with Mono (for Mac platform)

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have this C# function that work fine but unfortunately mono does not support `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface` Type for Mac platforms.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType Type = 0;

string MacAddress = ModSupBase.EMPTY_STRING;

try
{
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] theNetworkInterfaces = 
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface currentInterface in theNetworkInterfaces)
    {
        Type = currentInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;

        if (Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet 
            || Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.GigabitEthernet 
            || Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetFx)
        {
            MacAddress = currentInterface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

            break;
        }
    }

    return MacAddress;

}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    ModErrorHandle.Error_Handler(ex);

    return ModSupBase.EMPTY_STRING;
}
```

I have read this information using the mono migration utility (I think this is true)

there anoher way to get the MAC addrees with mono on MAC platform?

Thank you !

---

I don't known if work of not. I have only downloaded the last version of the mono migration utility and in the report I see:

> NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() Only works on Linux and Windows

I don't known if this true. Do you think is a false positive?

Comment: maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746840/get-mac-address-in-linux-using-mono

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Mono you are referring to? Looking at the Mono's trunk [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/NetworkInterface.cs) I'm pretty sure it is implemented now.

Comment: I don't known if work of not. I have only downloaded the last version of the mono migration utility and in the report I see:       NetworkInterface[] NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces () Only works on Linux and Windows

Comment: @user1320370: I would guess that the migration utility wasn't targeted at the latest version and just try to run it on Mac.