# Creating a computer ID using Mono

Tags: mono, licensing

I develop a few tools in C# using the .Net framework and I am considering the move to Mono. Based on the compatibility analyzer tool (MOMA), the only compatibility issue is the licensing code:

I use Window's serial number and a few other things to generate a computer ID which I then use to generate and manage my licenses.

Obviously, Windows will not be available on Linux or Mac, so I need another way to generate a  computer ID.

What can I use in mono to create a reasonably reliable computer ID?

Answer (score 3):

Use a MAC Address:

[Get MAC Address in linux using mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746840/get-mac-address-in-linux-using-mono)

That should be unique to a given network interface, which would uniquely identify the machine.

Also, see [this thread discussing the pitfalls and issues related to DRM](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/CPUID-td1506925.html) in mono.

Comment: Thanks, that could work, but i am a little concerned about how easily a mac address can be changed. Is there another option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of either CPUID and a hard drive serial number.

As for your code, there is not going to be an elegant way to do this with a one-liner. You will have to check which platform you are running on via [Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And then based on that, branch your code to do system-specific access. For example, to get CPUID/hdd serial number, use a WMI query; or parse the output of *hdparm -I /dev/hda* and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a portion of how Microsoft checked hardware for Windows XP [activation](http://www.technibble.com/windows-xp-activation-explained/). They checked 10 items

- Display Adapter
- SCSI Adapter
- IDE Adapter (effectively the motherboard)
- Network Adapter (NIC) and its MAC Address
- RAM Amount Range (i.e., 0-64mb, 64-128mb, etc.)
- Processor Type
- Processor Serial Number
- Hard Drive Device
- Hard Drive Volume Serial Number (VSN)
- CD-ROM / CD-RW / DVD-ROM

When XP was (re)installed/activated it'd contact their servers and if 7 or more of the above items were unchanged it would activate without the need to speak with anyone.

I, personally, would recommend against using the MAC address. As you mentioned, it can be easily changed. Additionally, most machines have two or more network cards now (wired and wireless). It gets worse with virtualization as the MAC can be changed even more easily than the physical one can (do you license differently for virtual environments?)

Another option, instead of checking all 10 hardware components, is to use the [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) of the [root file system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID). The downside of this, is that if the drive ever has issues, the license needs to be reacquired.

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: TYPE="ntfs" UUID="72C0DE8EC0DE57C5" LABEL="windows" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sda5: TYPE="swap" UUID="8c4e69f8-5074-42c0-8134-0b2429c4c02c" 
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="4848-E35A" TYPE="vfat"
```

Comment: sounds interesting, but how do you access any of this using mono in a way that will work regardless of the OS? (for me, the whole point of migrating to Mono is to use the same code for Windows, Mac and Linux)

Comment: @Sylverdrag The very nature of what you want to do is not going to be portable. If it was me I'd stick with your original approach for windows and use lspci or something on other platforms (though I don't know for sure if macs have lspci)